# How to pause a for loop at some specific iteration for 3 seconds in android?

Tags: android

I want to pause a for loop at the 50th iteration. I used Thread.sleep(3000) in the if condition but when the method is called, it hangs the whole method for 3 seconds before reaching the condition and the condition statement is working correctly (I checked it by putting Toast.makeText() in the condition)..
Please give me some solution to pause a for loop in android.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
     public void run()
     {
          // do your dummy work here or leave empty
     }
}, delay, period);
```

may work.

Comment: @Zeeshan Khalid it was working for me. But only thing which i couldn't be sure is i don't know whether it passes only 3 seconds or not

Comment: for me this is not working correctly.. if i put a toast in a run method my app shut downs with an unknown error "Unfortunately stopped working"
and with the empty run method it does nothing.. if you know what is the problem then please tell me

Comment: I've put this code in a try-catch box but it's not even giving the exception.

Comment: Or write run method outside some where and just call it inside timer..  May work

Comment: Okay.. I'll try and please tell me whats the function of 'period' in this method?

Comment: hey I've tried that. There's no change. it's still saying "Unfortunately stopped working" .. if I change period time to 0 then it's generating exception.. Tell me if you can solve it :P

Comment: `public class TimerDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // creating timer task
      TimerTask Yourtask = new TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay();
      Timer timer = new Timer();
      // scheduling the task at fixed rate delay
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Yourtask,2000,1000);      
   }
   // this method performs the task
   public void run() {
  //do nothing...
  boolean checkingvar = true;
  if(checkingvar){
   //end run();
  }
   }    
}`

Comment: and important thing is you need to end the function. otherwise it ll not finish... so use you logic...please

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `AsyncTask`. You can put your loop in there so it doesn't stop the whole UIThread. Also, I would recommend you to rethink your idea as continuing a method while wanting to have a "part" of it stopped is definitely not a good idea.